# Map in MapKit snaps back into original span every time firestore query returns

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, mapkit

So I know why this happens, but I wanted some suggestions on how to fix this. I save the coordinates of a user's friends in firestore. Everytime a user's coordinates update, the Map View updates and returns the span and centre to the original one. Again, I know why this is happening, but wanted some suggestions to know how to go around this. I'm guessing that some state variable is need. However, that will also reset every time the view reloads.

```
 @StateObject private var viewModel: LocationViewModel = LocationViewModel()
@State private var addPoint: Bool = false

@EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
@EnvironmentObject var friendsViewModel: FriendsViewModel
var region: Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>? {
    guard let location = viewModel.location else {
        return MKCoordinateRegion.goldenGateRegion().getBinding()
    }
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate,span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    return region.getBinding()
}


var points: [Marker] {
    
    var locations: [Marker] = []
    for friend in friendsViewModel.friends {
       
        if(friend.location?.latitude != nil && friend.location?.longitude != nil) {
            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: friend.location!.latitude, longitude: friend.location!.longitude)
            let x = Marker(location: coordinate, friendName: friend.name)
            locations.append(x)
        }
    
    }
    
    return locations
}

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if let region = region {
            
            Map(coordinateRegion: region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: points) {point in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: point.location) {
                    PlaceAnnotationView(title: point.friendName)
                }
            }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .tint(Color(.systemPink))
                
        }
```

Comment: Yes, you need to include code

Comment: Just did that, let me know if anything is to be explained

Comment: `getBinding` isn't a function on `MKCoordinateRegion` is it? I imagine you've defined that yourself?

Comment: yup i have defined that myself using an extension. it just returns a Binding<MKCoordinateRegion> just converts it into a Binding type

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. But it seems like you are doing a ton of overriding. The point of Binding is a two way connection you are changing that with all your functions and computed properties, you should simplify all that and use the standard $ with a single region

Comment: Understood, but i hardly think that's the solution to my problem. The main issue is that when published variable changes (in friendsVeiwModel), the entire MapView reloads. I wanted to know if there was a way to keep the current user zoom/span and allow the view to reload

Comment: That extension sounds likely to be the root of your problem. I don't see how it can work in this context. But, like @loremipsum's comment says, without a [mre], it's pretty hard to tell.

Comment: You will keep it by having a two way connection to a variable that can retain it. The map communicates this info but you are discarding it.

Comment: How am I discarding it?

Comment: Once you clean up the code you’ll find where you are doing the discarding. But my guess it is somewhere in that made up code that you aren’t showing. If you were keeping it it wouldn’t reset.