# SwiftUI: Display live map coordinates while moving

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, location, mapkit

I am making app where I need to get live coordinates of user and upload the newest coordinates every x minutes. I've been struggling with it for last few hours, and tried almost everything and checked all threads available and still don't have the answer.
Here is my code:

```
class LocationService: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    
    @Published var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    init(searchCompleter: MKLocalSearchCompleter = MKLocalSearchCompleter()) {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = CLLocationDistanceMax
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationService {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.first else { return }
        self.location = location
        print(location.coordinate)
    }
}

extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    static func goldenGateRegion() -> MKCoordinateRegion {
        MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.819527098978355, longitude:  -122.47854602016669), latitudinalMeters: 10, longitudinalMeters: 10)
    }
    func getBinding() -> Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>? {
        return Binding<MKCoordinateRegion>.constant(self)
    }
}
```

I am calling this function on main view:

```
.onChange(of: locationService.location) { newValue in
                print(newValue?.coordinate ?? "error")
            }
```

And I am getting same coordinates for the whole time, (I picked driveway location option in simulator).

Comment: Get rid of that “get binding” method. The whole point of a binding is a two-way connection. Constant breaks that, constant is only for previews. You need a published variable for the region and use “$” instead in your view. You already asked this under another profile https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75060048/map-in-mapkit-snaps-back-into-original-span-every-time-firestore-query-returns?noredirect=1#comment132458401_75060048